# How to use Repo.js

Tags: javascript, html, git, github

I am trying to use [Repo.js](http://darcyclarke.me/dev/repojs/#) on my website so that I can embed Github repositories in it.
I am a noob in Javascript and thus, have been having problems with setting it up.
This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" >    </script>

    <div id="repo1">
        <script src="RepoJS/repo.js">
            $('#repo1').repo({ user: 'darcyclarke', name: 'Repo.js' });
        </script>
    </div>

</body>
```

"RepoJS" is the folder where all the files from [HERE](https://github.com/darcyclarke/Repo.js) are located.

Could someone help me understand what I am doing srong, and how to fix it? Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The main problem you're running into is that `script` elements with `src` attributes should not have any contents, and [if they do, they're ignored](http://ejohn.org/blog/degrading-script-tags/); so where you have:

   ```
   <script src="RepoJS/repo.js">
       $('#repo1').repo({ user: 'darcyclarke', name: 'Repo.js' });
   </script>
   ```

   You instead need to have 2 separate `script` elements:

   ```
   <script src="RepoJS/repo.js"></script>
   <script>
       $('#repo1').repo({ user: 'darcyclarke', name: 'Repo.js' });
   </script>
   ```
2. It's a bad idea to have `script` elements in the middle of the page, standard practice is for them all to be in the `head` or at the end of the `body`. If you fix Problem 1 then your code *should* work, because the `<div id="repo1">` tag appears before the `script` element, but it's bad to rely on it (who know what the unwashed browsers will do), and elements defined after the `script` element won't be in the DOM yet.

   If you put all your scripts at the end of the `body`, as the other answer suggested, the whole DOM will be available immediately. If you put all your scripts in the `head`, they can be downloaded in parallel to finishing downloading and parsing the rest of the page, but you'll have to do:

   ```
   <script>
       $(function() {
           $('#repo1').repo({ user: 'darcyclarke', name: 'Repo.js' });
       });
   </script>
   ```

   which is jQuery's shortcut to wait for the DOM to be ready.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to register your scripts at the bottom of your page.

for `$('#repo1').repo({ user: 'darcyclarke', name: 'Repo.js' });` you have to use a separate script-tag or to write it in a separate script-file.

so, this should work..

```
<body>
  <div id="repo1"></div>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="RepoJS/repo.js"><script>
  <script type="javascript">
    $('#repo1').repo({ user: 'darcyclarke', name: 'Repo.js' });
  </script>
</body>
```